# SPARQL - Number of awards per actor?

Tags: database, sparql, wikidata

I would like to get the list of actors in Wikidata and also the number of awards received by each of them. Which query do I have to write ?

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work because I have only a few results :

```
SELECT ?actor ?actorLabel ?awardsNumber WHERE {
{
    SELECT ?actor (COUNT(DISTINCT ?awardsNumber) AS ?awardsNumber) 
    WHERE {
       ?actor wdt:P106 wd:Q33999 .
       ?awardsNumber wdt:P166 ?actor .   
    }  
    GROUP BY ?actor
}         
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
}
ORDER BY DESC (?awardsNumber)
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you used the property `P166` ("award received") as incoming property. Of course the query must be

```sql
SELECT ?actor ?actorLabel ?awardsNumber WHERE {
{
    SELECT ?actor (COUNT(DISTINCT ?award) AS ?awardsNumber) 
    WHERE {
       ?actor wdt:P106 wd:Q33999 .
       ?actor wdt:P166 ?award.   
    }  
    GROUP BY ?actor
}         
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
}
ORDER BY DESC (?awardsNumber)
```

Comment: Thanks ! I just used it because the received awards are linked to the actors through this property and I didn't find another way to figure out my problem.